How to get the name=value pairs of all loaded properties files in a SpringBoot application
I work with a SpringBoot application which has a lot of .properties files in several different directories. The directories are listed using:
-Dspring.config.additional-location= and then within those, there are profiles pointed to by the
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
      <configuration>
        <profiles>
          <profile>PROFILE_1</profile>
          <profile>PROFILE_2</profile>
          <profile>PROFILE_3</profile>

This causes a problem when either a key is repeated in multiple places (which one is being used???), or when multiple properties files have the same name (which one overrides which????).
What I want to do is have my app. output ALL key-value pairs on startup (when a debug flag is set!) from all application.properties or application-XXX.properties files it is reading from.
This doesn't seem to be as simple as I thought it would be.
I've researched this on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but the closest I can find is this:
Is there a way to get list of loaded properties file in SpringBoot application?
I've been playing with the code in that question for a while but I can only make it give me the value of any given key, not the list of ALL key-value pairs.
This must have been done before? Or is there a security reason why it is blocked?

The code in that thread iterates over all propertysources, and prints all keys/values from that propertysource. That seems exactly what you need.

What will it do if the same kv pair is in two? It will print both out right? Is it printing in the correct order? As-in, the later one would over-write the earlier in memory? @m-deinum

The last one loaded is the one that will be used. So depending on how you iterate it will show the correct order.
